# djangoの導入ができません

Tags: python, python3, django

djangoのインストールはできています。
シェルでdjangoをimportとして、バージョンを表示させようとしても以下のエラーが出ます。

```
AttributeError: module 'django' has no attribute 'version'
```

解決方法を教えてください。

Comment: django のインストールができていると思った理由を教えて頂けませんか？

Comment: `django` という名前のディレクトリの近くで作業なされてませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> django.VERSION
(2, 0, 4, 'final', 0)
```

こうすべきところで、以下のようにしてるのではないですかね？

```
>>> django.version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'django' has no attribute 'version'
```

Comment: 以下のようにしていました笑 上のようにしてみたら無事表示されました！ありがとうございます！！